# PHP Form issues with action and echoing result

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am trying to get a simple two-field form to submit to an email address and then echo a "thanks for registering your interest" below the form (or instead of the form).

FYI, this is on a WordPress template file.

Here is the code, including the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
method="POST" autocomplete="on" id="register-form">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Send
<img src="<?= get_image('icon-arrow-right-tiny.svg'); ?>"/></button>

</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// validate the email address first
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
// process the form only if the email is valid
if ($email) {
    $to = 'info@example.com'; // where you want to send the mail
    $from = 'info@mydomain.com';
    $subject = 'Website Submission';
    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= 'Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-to: $email";
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
} ?>
<p style='color: #fff; font-size: 14px;'>Thank you for registering your interest.</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

At the present time, the form does get sent, and the page does echo "Thank you for registering your interest" underneath the form, however it does not seem to be returning us to the correct page when you click the submit button.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you cal the correct page?

Comment: What is the value of :

<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> 
in your html generated page?

Comment: example.com/index.php - which is correct in that if I copy and paste this link into a new tab it loads the right page, but the main content of the page is not getting pulled through when I submit the form, only the header and footer are being shown.

Comment: Ah, I got it, you check a $_POST['submit'], but this field is the submit button, check a post of a real field (email or name). I dont get why this statement is true because you have not posted a submit field. Maybe you have another form posted somewhere?

Comment: @NicolasD That is not the problem here. The Thank you message is being printed, which is in the same If statement. So the code is going into the If statement.

Comment: it doesn't return to the correct page; well, the form's action is set to self, so it's staying on the same page. If you want to redirect somewhere, you'll have to use a JS solution or meta refresh in order to both echo the thank you AND redirect. You can't do a header location with an echo.

Comment: @ me if you need me, moving on.

Comment: @Richard Grandi your code is working well, I think if you are posting data on same page then you dont need to give action, try removing $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; if your main concern is related with the redirecting point of view then you can pass the Current page URL as an hidden value and redirect after email success to that URL hope this will you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all of your contributions. I have worked out the problem, and will share here for anybody else who comes here to find the answer.

WordPress has something important reserved for the "name" parameter, and thus you can't use it in PHP-based forms. Changing the parameter name from "name" to something else resolved the issue.

Additionally, WordPress also has the following names reserved and you cannot use them in forms - "day" "month" and "year".

Comment: You have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code i think you have use color code #fff i.e. for the message. 
Please try to make black or any other color rest of code are working.
:)

Thank you for registering your interest.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put a php code below your Thank you message.

header("location:$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);exit;

Comment: This will not work, you mean ``header("Location: ". $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); exit; ``

Comment: Please also write why he need that.

Comment: You can use this whenever you are done with the execution and want to redirect to a specific page. You can also specify the page here.
header("Location:index.php");

Comment: Badly this is wrong, you can't use ``header(..)`` after you output something, so you'r whole answer is wrong.